# Measure scroll velocity Javascript and trigger event

Tags: javascript

I would like to trigger an event when the window scroll velocity goes above a certain value. I found some code that will help measure the velocity but I can't work out why the `if` statement is not triggered when the speed goes above 150. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const checkScrollSpeed = (function(settings){
    settings = settings || {};

    let lastPos, newPos, timer, delta, 
        delay = settings.delay || 50;

    function clear() {
        lastPos = null;
        delta = 0;
    }

    clear();

    return function(){
        newPos = window.scrollY;
        if ( lastPos != null ){ // && newPos < maxScroll 
            delta = newPos -  lastPos;
        }
        lastPos = newPos;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(clear, delay);
        return delta;
    };
})();

const container = document.querySelector('#container');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log(checkScrollSpeed());
    if (checkScrollSpeed() > 150) {
        console.log('150+')
        container.classList.add('red');
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 75%;
  height: 170vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#container.red {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you have a little delay between the first time you call `checkScrollSpeed()` in your `console.log` and then in your `if` statement. You can try to call it only once and save the value for your `console.log` and `if` statement. It works for me with this solution:

```js
const checkScrollSpeed = (function(settings) {
  settings = settings || {};

  let lastPos, newPos, timer, delta,
      delay = settings.delay || 50;

  function clear() {
    lastPos = null;
    delta = 0;
  }

  clear();

  return function() {
    newPos = window.scrollY;
    if (lastPos != null) { // && newPos < maxScroll
      delta = newPos - lastPos;
    }
    lastPos = newPos;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(clear, delay);
    return delta;
  };
})();

const container = document.querySelector('#container');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var speed = checkScrollSpeed();
  console.log(speed);
  if (speed > 150) {
    console.log('150+');
    container.classList.add('red');
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 75%;
  height: 170vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#container.red {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `checkScrollSpeed` in succession and when it's called the second time delta is 0.  Either remove the `console.log` or assign delta to some variable and use that for logging and the condition.